# Pandas throws ValueError while converting to datetime from string

Tags: pandas

I have an excel sheet with a column that is supposed to contain date values but pandas reads it as float64. It has blanks

```
df:
date_int
15022016
23072017
```

I want to convert to a datetime object. I do:

```
df['date_int1'] = df['date_int'].astype(str).fillna('01011900')#To fill the blanks
df['date_int2']=pd.to_datetime(df['date_int1'],format='%d%m%Y')
```

I get error while converting to datetime:

```
TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>
ValueError: unconverted data remains: .0
```

Comment: df['date_int'].astype(int).astype(str).fillna('01011900')

Comment: Thank you, I get: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't convert to string until you've filled the NaNs. Otherwise, the NaNs are also stringified, and at the point there is nothing to fill.

```
df

     date_int
0  15022016.0
1  23072017.0
2         NaN

df['date_int'] = df['date_int'].fillna(1011900, downcast='infer').astype(str)
pd.to_datetime(df['date_int'], format='%d%m%Y', errors='coerce')

0   2016-02-15
1   2017-07-23
2   1900-01-10
Name: date_int, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

See comment from @Wen-Ben. Convert the data to int first.

`df.date_int = df.date_int.astype(int)`

Then the rest of the code will work fine.